# ActiveCollab API - return only open tickets

Tags: activecollab

Currently I see only this option in the documentation

> projects/:project_id/tasks
>
> This command lists all open and completed non-archived Tasks from a
>   Project.

Is there a filter or parameter (or another API call) I can pass to get back only the open tasks which are not completed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCollab 4 works the way you described. If you need only open tasks, you sould filter the result when your app receives it.

In ActiveCollab 5, there are separate API resources for open and completed tasks, so upgrade is one possible path to behavior that you want.